# Integer solutions to $|-3+p|=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, absolute-value, integers

Given that $ = −3$ is a solution to $|x+p| = 5$, find the two values of $p$, where $p \in \Bbb{Z}$.

I am familiar with complex numbers, I knew I should get acquainted for a question like this.
From my understanding; The absolute value of a complex number is the number that is obtained by taking the real part of the complex number and the number that is obtained by taking the imaginary part of the complex number.
Thus, $|x+p| = |x + i y| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 5$ (from the question)
Thus surely that would make
0 = 5 which shouldn't be possible- I think!
How do I explain this to my Professor?

Comment: There are 2 real (edit: in fact, they are required by the problem statement to be integers and they are) solutions to this problem. Are you familiar with absolute value?

Comment: Why are you bringing complex numbers into this?  Either $x+p > 0$, and so $|x+p| = x+p$; or $x+p < 0$, and $|x+p| = -x-p$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on $|x+p| = |x+iy|$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I was referring to separating |x+p| into its complex form- regards

Comment: I always read this kind of equation as "the distance from $x$ to $-p$ is $5$" and then it becomes easy to solve - or if you insist, draw a diagram in the complex plane.

Comment: @Muskballhair Seems like $x$ is doing double-duty in the notation. You might want to clear that up. EG Are you claiming that $ x+p = x+iy \Rightarrow p = iy$?

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, this is not a complex analysis question.  That is because one of the problem constraints is that $p \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Therefore, focus may be restricted to those values of $p$ that are Real numbers, that (also) happen to be integers.  Therefore,  this problem actually represents the issue of how to manage a math problem that includes an absolute value.

In general, if you have a problem that contains an expression like $|f(x)|$, the simplest approach is to consider $2$ cases.  Either $f(x) \geq 0$ or $f(x) < 0.$

The following (rather inelegant) approach may be used to attack problems of this type.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1} ~(-3 + p) \geq 0}$

$(-3 + p) \geq 0 \iff p \geq 3.$ 
In that event, $|-3 + p| = (+1) \times (-3 + p) = (-3 + p).$

Therefore, in this individual case, the problem becomes 
$(-3 + p) = 5 \implies p = 8.$

So, in case 1, the only solutions allowable will be values of $p$ that satisfy **all** of the following constraints:

- $p \geq 3.$
- $p = 8.$
- $p$ is an integer.

Since $p = 8$ satisfies all of the above constraints, this represents the Case 1 solution.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2} ~(-3 + p) < 0}$

$(-3 + p) < 0 \iff p < 3.$ 
In that event, $|-3 + p| = (-1) \times (-3 + p) = (3 - p).$

Therefore, in this individual case, the problem becomes 
$(3 - p) = 5 \implies p = -2.$

So, in case 2, the only solutions allowable will be values of $p$ that satisfy **all** of the following constraints:

- $p < 3.$
- $p = -2.$
- $p$ is an integer.

Since $p = -2$ satisfies all of the above constraints, this represents the Case 2 solution.

---

Final Answer:

Case 1: $p = 8.$
Case 2: $p = -2.$

Therefore, the two solutions are $p \in \{-2,8\}.$

Answer (score -3):

As you correctly managed to work out, you are looking for a solution to √x2+y2=5. So I would suggest drawing a circle of radius 5 and then finding the y values where x = -3. This should give you your solutions for P, which may or may not be imaginary, I haven't bothered to put any thought into trying to solve

Comment: He does not bother us, his problem, I think, is a valid one. The word "trivial" depends on the knowledge you have in that related area. Better to use LATEX not to bother us.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).